# How can I use my SoloKey v2 as key for encrypting my OS?

Tags: arch-linux, disk-encryption

I have installed Blackarch Linux on my PC. Now I wanted to encrypt the whole SSD.

Instead of typing a password in, I wanted to use my SoloKey v2. Is it possible that I am only able to use my PC if the key is in, and the machine gets encrypted if I pull it out?

Comment: that's not how encryption works. The data is always encrypted at rest; the difference the physical key would make is that it can contain the cryptographic key to decrypt the data on the SSD. That means both the key and the decrypted data end up in RAM. You can erase the key from RAM using the appropriate LUKS commands, but it won't change the fact that the data you're currently using is decrypted in RAM. It will have the effect that any program trying to *access* some data that's not currently in RAM will fail. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, so, if I only want to use it as decryption key instead of a password, is that possible? And how can I do that?